# XCode 6.1: Weird behaviour in Swift code highlighting

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, codehighlighter

I just started to take a look into Swift but `XCode` is messing up the code highlighting. As shown in the picture below

[image]

Due some bad performance issues with Swift, I am using `XCode Version 6.1 (Beta)`, but had the same problem with `XCode 6.0`. This usually appears at the end of classes?

I tried clean projects, reload project, reopen files, rebooting system but it doesn't disappear, it just changes the colors randomly....

Anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Xcode 6.1 GM 2 (released few days ago).